# Twilio - Call Recording Http authentication - not getting redirect url

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I enabled HTTP Basic Authentication on my Twilio account under Voice->Settings->General

Then created a voice recording and was able to download it using my account SID & Auth Token

```
curl -X GET "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACxxx/Recordings/RExxx" \
-u ACxxx:xxx
```

I need to be able to access the recording from a web client, without exposing my Twilio Auth Token to the public.
According to Twilio docs, I should get a redirect Url, when fetching the recording, but in my above curl example I don't.

https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223183748-Protect-Media-Access-with-HTTP-Basic-Authentication-for-Programmable-Messaging

> Requests to fetch your media will redirect you to a secure URL that is only valid for 4 hours.

I get the same result (recording is downloaded) if I use Authorization header

```
curl -X GET "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACxxx/Recordings/RExxx" \
-H "Authorization: Basic xxx"
```

Any ideas, why I am not getting redirect Url mentioned in Twilio docs?

Comment: Did you make a new recording after you enabled Enforce HTTP Auth on Media URLs? Recordings from prior to enabling can still be accessed from the "public" URL. Only recordings after enabling are protected.

Comment: @jassent Yes I made a recording after, as I stated in my description. Prior recordings cannot be accessed from the public URL, after http basic is enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened a ticket with twilio support and they acknowledged there is no support for redirect urls with temporary tokens, for recordings.

They recommended to use Auth tokens, but as I mentioned in the description, this is something I am not willing to do (expose auth tokens to UI)

Comment: An alternative, is to download the Twilio recording to your own blob storage (like Azure or AWS). Twilio has a built-in integration with AWS. You can then use the blob storage provider to issue the temporary tokens. Azure calls the temporary tokens "SAS tokens". I am sure AWS has something similar. Another option might be to generate Twilio Access Tokens - those might work with the redirect URLs and can be set to expire (https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/access-tokens).